# Design tabela de "workflow"

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, cakephp

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em Cakephp e gostaria da ajuda de vocês em qual seria o melhor jeito de criar o meu banco de dados e minha relação entre os *models*.

Seria um "workflow".

Gostaria que funcionasse da seguinte maneira:

1- Essa aplicação terá vários grupos e esses grupos, vários usuários.

2- Cada solicitação teria o seu fluxo, podendo várias solicitações ter o mesmo fluxo.

3- O "administrador" poderá criar vários fluxos de trabalho, com até 5 passos, entre grupos e pessoas.
Exemplo:

```
Primeiro Aprovador | Segundo Aprovador | Terceiro Aprovador | Quarto Aprovador | Quinto
 Grupo Delta           Joao                    Pedro            Grupo Alfa        NULL
```

4- Quando o administrador escolhesse um grupo, e não um usuário específico, seria sorteado alguem desse grupo.

5- As aprovações seguiriam a ordem, ou seja, o próximo só pode aprovar se o anterior já tiver aprovado.

Acho que é basicamente isso.

Realmente isso está me dando muito trabalho. Não estou conseguindo pensar em nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiquei 6 entidades (tabelas) me baseando na sua descrição do problema, são elas:

1. Pessoa
2. Usuario
3. Grupo
4. Fluxo
5. Solicitacao
6. Passo

A relação entre elas segue a ordem do texto:

```
Grupo 1+ <---> 1+ Usuario //dado um Grupo, ele possui 1 ou mais usuários
                          //dado um Usuario, ele está em 1 ou mais grupos

Solicitacao 1+ <---> 1 Fluxo //dada uma Solicitacao, ele possui apenas 1 fluxo
                             //dado um Fluxo, ele possui 1 ou mais solicitações

Passo 1-5 <---> 1 Fluxo //dado um Passo, ele está em apenas um fluxo
                        //dado um Fluxo, ele possui de 1 a 5 passos

Passo 1 <---> 1 Pessoa //dado um Passo, ele pode ser uma Pessoa

Passo 1 <---> 1 Grupo //dado um Passo, ele poder ser um Grupo
```

Até o item 3 de sua descrição identifiquei que se trata da especificação do Model desse aplicativo, do 4º em diante temos especificações sobre regras de negócio.

Abaixo segue o modelo de dados. Nele eu utilizei uma notação genérica para representar as tabelas e acredito ser bem simples traduzi-lo para qualquer banco de dados.

```
Pessoa
  - id (pk)
  - nome

Usuario
  - id (pk)
  - login
  - senha

Grupo
  - id (pk)
  - nome

Grupo_Usuarios
  - grupo_id   (fk)
  - usuario_id (fk)
  - primary_key (grupo_id, usuario_id)

Fluxo 
  - id (pk)
  - descricao

Solicitacao
  - id (pk)
  - data
  - fluxo_id (fk)

Passo
  - id (pk)
  - numero
  - fluxo_id (fk)
  - unique (numero, fluxo_id)
  - check (numero > 0 AND numero < 5) //indexado em 0. Valores permitidos de 0 a 4 (cinco valores)

//caso o passo seja para uma Pessoa, inserir registro nessa tabela
Passo_Pessoa
  - passo_id  (fk)
  - pessoa_id (fk)
  - primary_key (passo_id, pessoa_id)

//caso o passo seja para um Grupo, inserir registro nessa tabela
Passo_Grupo
  - passo_id (fk)
  - grupo_id (fk)
  - primary_key (passo_id, grupo_id)
```

Comment: Olá. Sua resposta me colocou no caminho certo para conseguir oq eu queria. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que modelar com informações nas tabelas seja o ideal, apontando a ordem de cada passo.

Um exemplo que você pode adaptar à sua necessidade:

Tabelas

```
Grupo {id, nome}
Usuario {id, nome}
Membro {idGrupo, idUsuario}
Fluxo {id, titulo, descricao}
Fluxo_Passo {idFluxo, passo, idGrupoResponsavel, idUsuarioResponsavel, idUsuarioAprovou, aprovado}
```

Usar valores nulos em Grupo e Usuario responsável para mútua exclusão. Esta regra deve ser tratada no código da aplicação.
Se existir a necessidade de escolher um responsável aleatório para um grupo, também tratar no código no momento em que o passo é salvo no banco, mas este procedimento também pode deixar somente o grupo indicado e não o usuário, assim qualquer membro do grupo poderia assumir.

Usar um campo explícito para o id usuário de aprovou pode permitir substituição. Também, somente permita que um passo seja executado se não é nulo o campo aprovado é verdadeiro em idFluxo passo -1.

Espero que ajude.